# Openpyxl copy a sheet with named ranges

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, streamlit

I could copy the sheet that i need but it does not copy with the named ranges, so in the cell i have the NAME error because formulas are using that names to make calculus. Of course names needs to match the address.
Whats the proper way to do it?

Here's my code.

```
def write_to_template_sheet(input_filename, value_to_write):
    try:
        # Cargar el archivo Excel
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(input_filename)

        # Crear una copia de la hoja "Template"
        template_sheet = wb["Template"]
        new_sheet = wb.copy_worksheet(template_sheet)

        # Contar el número de hojas que comienzan con "P"
        hojas_con_p = [nombre for nombre in wb.sheetnames if nombre.startswith('P')]
        numero_hojas_con_p = len(hojas_con_p)

        # Renombrar la nueva hoja con "P" seguido del número de hojas con "P"
        new_sheet.title = f"P{numero_hojas_con_p +1}"

        # Copiar datos y formatos
        for row in template_sheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=template_sheet.max_row, min_col=1, max_col=template_sheet.max_column):
            
            for cell in row:
                    new_cell = new_sheet[cell.coordinate]
                    new_cell.value = cell.value
                   
        # Escribir el valor en la fila 31, columna 2 de la nueva hoja
        new_sheet.cell(row=31, column=2, value=value_to_write)

        # Guardar los cambios en el archivo
        wb.save(input_filename)

        st.success('Saved successfully')
        except Exception as e:
        st.error(f'Error: {str(e)}')


st.title("Create a project")


value_to_write = st.text_input("Name of the proyect", "",key="Project_Name")


if st.button("Save"):
    input_filename = "wbtool.xlsx"  # Nombre del archivo original
    write_to_template_sheet(input_filename, value_to_write)
```

I have tried

```
import streamlit as st
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('wbtool.xlsx')
sh = wb\['Template'\]
allnames=list(sh.defined_names.names)

st.write(allnames)
```

but I do not realize how to use it for copy not onlye the names but address as well.

Comment: Be mindful of your indentation in python.

Answer (score 0):

You have made a copy of the sheet using  Openpyxl 'copy_worsheet' function

```
new_sheet = wb.copy_worksheet(template_sheet)
```

So the later commands looping through the cells and copying the values at **# Copiar datos y formatos** is redundant. This section is not going to do anything that 'copy_worksheet' didn't already do.

For the defined names; after the new sheet is created you can just read and recreate. 
In this example I am assuming the template defined names are scoped to that sheet since otherwise the new created sheet would just use the name from workbook scope and not return a 'NAME error'. 
Therefore the search for the defined names to copy is on the sheet, i.e. `template_sheet.defined_names`.

```
for name, items in template_sheet.defined_names.items():
```

If the defined names are scoped to the workbook, the workbook object defined names needs to be used instead, `wb.defined_names`, so the code would need to be modified. 
To obtain the details we simply read the defined names from 'template_sheet` and recreate and add to the new sheet for each defined name.

```
import openpyxl
import streamlit as st


def write_to_template_sheet(input_filename, value_to_write):
    try:
        # Cargar el archivo Excel
        wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(input_filename)

        # Crear una copia de la hoja "Template"
        template_sheet = wb["Template"]
        ### Copies the sheet here all styling and values (but not defined names)
        new_sheet = wb.copy_worksheet(template_sheet)

        # Contar el número de hojas que comienzan con "P"
        hojas_con_p = [nombre for nombre in wb.sheetnames if nombre.startswith('P')]
        numero_hojas_con_p = len(hojas_con_p)

        # Renombrar la nueva hoja con "P" seguido del número de hojas con "P"
        new_sheet.title = f"P{numero_hojas_con_p + 1}"

        ### Copy the defined names 
        for name, items in template_sheet.defined_names.items():
            ### change the sheet name in the coordinates
            coords = items.attr_text.replace(template_sheet.title, new_sheet.title)
            ### Create the new defined name for the new sheet using the same defined name e.g. data1 
            ### and the coords from the template sheet with sheet name changed
            new_dn = openpyxl.workbook.defined_name.DefinedName(
                name, attr_text=coords)
            ### Add the defined name scoped to the sheet
            new_sheet.defined_names.add(new_dn)

        ### This section is redundant cell values are already copied
        # Copiar datos y formatos
        # for row in template_sheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=template_sheet.max_row, min_col=1,
        #                                     max_col=template_sheet.max_column):
        #
        #     for cell in row:
        #         new_cell = new_sheet[cell.coordinate]
        #         new_cell.value = cell.value

        # Escribir el valor en la fila 31, columna 2 de la nueva hoja
        new_sheet.cell(row=31, column=2, value=value_to_write)

        # Guardar los cambios en el archivo
        wb.save(input_filename)

        st.success('Saved successfully')
    except Exception as e:
        st.error(f'Error: {str(e)}')
```